# Count properties in a large data set via SPARQL

Tags: sparql, virtuoso

I'd like to have a list of most used properties in a SPARQL endpoint. The most straightforward query would be:

```
select ?p ( count ( distinct * ) as ?ct )
{
  ?s ?p ?o. 
}
group by ?p
order by desc ( ?ct )
limit 1000
```

The problem is that there are too many triples (1.6 billions) and the server times out. So, after googling, I've also tried this, to get at least a sample statistics (yes, it's Virtuoso-specific and it's fine in my case):

```
select ?p ( count ( distinct * ) as ?ct )
{
  ?s ?p ?o. 
  FILTER ( 1 > <SHORT_OR_LONG::bif:rnd> (0.0001, ?s, ?p, ?o) )
}
group by ?p
order by desc ( ?ct )
limit 1000
```

But it times out anyway, I guess because it still has to `group`, `count` and then `order`. So, how can I do it? I have access to the Virtuoso relational DB (i.e., iSQL), but I cannot find docs about SQL syntax and how to select random triples from the table `db.dba.rdf_quad`.

**EDIT**: I've fixed the queries, initially they were wrong, thanks for the comments. The versions above still don't work.

Comment: Side note: I don't think that query really counts the most used properties, you should remove distinct, otherwise each group will have the number 1 as count.

Comment: Yep, or count ?s or ?o, but again no distinct.

Comment: Sorry, I've messed up too many open windows, now I've fixed the queries, but they don't work yet.

Comment: 1. Would you be willing to try some optimizations of the virtuoso.ini file?  2. Are you issuing the query across a network, like via a web browser?  i.e., could you log into the shell of the virtuoso server and submit the query to localhost, for example with cURL?

Comment: As @MarkMiller already said. There is no space for improvement regarding the query itself. Anything else relies on the performance of the triple store which in fact is based on the hardware it is deployed on.

Comment: A workaround could be to use some client side code which iterates over the properties and executes a count query for each property. That would at least remove some load from the triple store.

Comment: Ah, and as the other already said, no need to use `DISTINCT` - there can't be duplicates `(s,o)` for a property `p` as RDF is a set of triples `(s,p,o)`

Comment: Uhm, I think there might be dupes when merging named graphs.

Comment: Not enough information here… Always key to know [what version of Virtuoso is running](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtCheckSvrVersionViaSparql), and whether you've [tuned its settings to optimize use of system resources (memory, especially)](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtRDFPerformanceTuning).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I've found a way, at least a partial one: Virtuoso has a command line administration tool, `isql`. This accepts `SPARQL` queries as well, in the form: `SPARQL <query>;`. And they're executed without timeout or result size restrictions.

This is still not good if you can only access an endpoint via HTTP, I don't quite know if that way it is possible at all.

Comment: Some restrictions affect interaction via HTML but not via iSQL, ODBC, JDBC, or other mechanisms; other restrictions affect all interaction. If the Virtuoso instance is your own, you can adjust the configuration to optimize performance, and adjust the limits so they don't impact your queries. The [Virtuoso Users mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/virtuoso-users/) is a good place to ask Virtuoso-specific questions.

Comment: thanks @TallTed, I had read somewhere that there are these config options, I think I'll change them, but what I can't figure out is a simple way to list properties and their usage, which doesn't take too long time. Maybe triple stores should introduce some statistics graph, where one can get these things on the flight.

Comment: This isn't a great place for such conversation, but a key detail is — Why do you want these stats? What's the purpose, the goal, the end result? [Maybe there's a better way](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)…

Comment: I think they might be useful for several purposes. Eg, - telling users/stakeholders about what you have in a knowledge base (and how it's growing) - evaluate resources you need for an application (e.g., memor/nodes/time to analyse data) - reverse engineering a data set to build a proper ontology over it (my current case).

Comment: You may find [this article](https://joernhees.de/blog/2015/01/28/dbpedia-2014-stats-top-subjects-predicates-and-objects/) an interesting read.